# solr stemmer does not match plurals

Tags: solr

I am trying to get solr search to work both on singular and plurals, but I am having a had time to get this to work. So, my schema uses `text_en` like so:

```
  <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

I then copy this field (say `foods`) to `_text_` and then query like so:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/food_db/select?q=chickens
```

But this does not seem to pick up content with `chicken`. When I do this however:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/food_db/select?q=chicken
```

I get the relevant output.

I was under the impression that the stemmer helps with the singular/plural issue, but it does not seem to be the case.

Any clarity on this would be great.

Comment: You can use the `Analysis` page under Solr Admin to see exactly what is happening for each step - that way you can see why indexing "chickens" and searching for "chicken" (or the other way around) doesn't generate the same tokens. Add the output to your question and it should be easier to say where it goes awry.

Comment: What field type is your `_text_` field? By default `_text_` is `text_general` and that will not handle plurals (you can see this the Analysis screen as MatsLindh pointed out). The default `text_en` will handle plurals properly, you also see that in the Analysis screen. If `food` is of type `text_en` this should work: http://localhost:8983/solr/food_db/select?q=food:chickens (notice that I am searching on the `food` fields, rather than on the default `_text_` field)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `PorterStemFilterFactory` in your fields type the it will stem the words. Please refer the below example.

Example:

```
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory "/>
  <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

**In**: `"jump jumping jumped"`

**Tokenizer to Filter**: `"jump", "jumping", "jumped"`

**Out**: `"jump", "jump", "jump"`

Note : You can try the same analysis in the solr admin page. It helps you to check what are the tokens created and which are matching.

[Solr Documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html)

Comment: May I ask why? Is that not the whole point of using stemming?

Comment: @JohnJ: I hope the example clears the question. Because of stemming, the tokens are not created at solr end and hence the result is not achieved.

Comment: thank you for this, but I am slightly confused. I thought the stemmer is used to match singular and plural values. Is this not the case?

Comment: You are welcome. Stemmer chops or slice the words as shown above. The original word is not preserved.

Comment: what is correct way to get solr to match both singular and plural versions? I was originally using `text_general` field and then now switched to `text_en`, but I am unsure if this is the correct field I should be using..

Comment: I have tried removing it as you have described but it does not seem to help. If I use q="chickens" I see no results with "chicken"

Comment: @JohnJ : Did you tried this in the solr analysis page? If you have a word indexed with chickens then only you will be able to get the result for the word chicken. If you want wildcard search like "chike*" which will get the chicken and chickens both in the result. To achive the same you may need to change the fieldtype of the field to string...If you want to have lowercase support then use keywordtokenizer and lowercasefilterfactoy